# cannot read property 'map' of undefined react js, mockup project playlist generator

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am following a certain online course, and now is building some sort of playlist generator and then exporting it to spotify. the main component is App.js, which receives three components of `searchBar`, `SearchResult` and `playList`.

the problem is inside the `searchResult` component which receives another component called `trackList`. inside the `trackList` i tried to map the tracks array but returned undefined. i am sure have defined the tracks using `this.props` inside the `searchResults`.

```
//this is SearchResults 
import React from 'react';
import './SearchResults.css';
import TrackList from '../Tracklist/TrackList';

class SearchResults extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="SearchResults">
                <h2>Results</h2>
            <TrackList tracks={this.props.searchResults}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default SearchResults;
```

```
// and this is TrackList
import React from 'react';
import './TrackList.css';
import Track from '../Track/Track';

class TrackList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="TrackList">
                {
                    this.props.tracks.map(track => {
                        return <Track track={track} key={track.id} />
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default TrackList;
```

```
//this is the parent component
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

import SearchBar from '../SearchBar/SearchBar';
import SearchResults from '../SearchResult/SearchResults';
import Playlist from '../Playlist/Playlist';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      searchResults: [{name: 'name1', artist: 'artist1', album: 'album1', id: 1},
      {name: 'name2', artist: 'artist2', album: 'album2', id: 2},
      {name: 'name3', artist: 'artist3', album: 'album3', id: 3}]
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Ja<span className="highlight">mmm</span>ing</h1>
        <div className="App">
          <SearchBar />
          <div className="App-playlist">
            <SearchResults searchResults={this.state.searchResults}/>
            <Playlist searchResult={this.state.searchResult}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

I expect the code to run and generate the tracks which consists of `name`,`artist` and `album`, but instead returned map undefined.

I hope my question is clear and concise enough, thank you.

Comment: Could you also show the parent component of SearchResults? I think maybe the searchResults prop is undefined

Comment: i have updated the parent component, App.js

Comment: Your code works as intended: https://jsfiddle.net/oauz4pev/

Comment: Could it be that error is not from `SearchResults`, but from `SearchBar` or `Playlist`?

Comment: but in my localhost it shows typeError map undefined, how is that so?

Comment: the error originated from my TrackList.js, which connected to Tracklist,SearchResult and eventually to App.js. i don't see any connection to the searchbar and playlist